# Azure Mobile App Application Key

Tags: windows, azure, mobile

i have an Mobile App on Azure. All Works like Charm, but the i can´t configure the Access. There is an Application Key, this one should prevent the Mobile App. But it doesen´t. I can directly send a request to the mobile app
http://myappname-code.azurewebsites.net/tables/User/3 and an answer returned, without prompting for the Application Key set in the azure preview portal.

Things i tried:

- Regenerate Key
- Restart Gateway
- Restart mobile app code

the same project as Mobile Service works perfect, but as mobile app there are only ghost errors.

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: You are saying that your app was a Mobile Service before and is now a Mobile App, right? Is this the migration process that you followed? 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-migrating-from-mobile-services-preview/

Comment: Hi Amanda, yes first i followed that process but it´s didn´t fit with my code first. Or i created a bug that i find out later it wasn't a problem with the process. It was a aproblem with my think process :-) What i want to say, i deleted the old mobile service an build a new mobile app from scratch, import my old model and Controller, works fine, until the Application Key Deilema. I had created a new Application Key in the Preview Portal, but now i had no Key :-) When in want to create a new one only an error apperas in the box :-) Workaround since this -> rebuild the "old" mobile service.

Answer (score 4):

The migration process isn't perfect yet, so if it's working for you as a Mobile Service, you may just want to stick with it for now. (which you discovered) But if you need the features of Mobile Apps now, Mobile Apps work a bit more like Web Apps. There's still a way to generate codes on the preview portal, but try looking here for a different set of authorizations: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-debug/ There's a troubleshooting link at the bottom there too if you run into other issues with the Mobile Apps.

Comment: Hi Amanda, this doesent solve my Problem. This Time i had no Need to change on App Services. But in the Future im feel not Save to change to App Service, i Hope they doesent deprecate the mobile Service in azure. Thanks for the Link, i will Study. :)